# ASP.NET controller method for ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a page with a multiselect list of strings. When I select multiple items and hit apply I want to make an ajax call and pass in the values. When I debug the method in the controller the parameter is empty.

HomeController

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetTopLogEvents(string[] filters)
{
    // ........
    return "";
}
```

scripts.js

```
$('.js-event-level-filter-apply').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $filterList = $('.js-event-level-filter');
    var filters = $filterList.val();

    var obj = {
        filters: []
    };

    $.each(filters, function(key, value) {
        obj.filters.push(value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/GetTopLogEvents',
        data: obj.filters,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

If I put a breakpoint in the controller it hits, but filters is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read how parameter binding works?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you need to "stringify" your array.

I would firstly change the ajax data section to look like this:

```
data: {filters: obj.filters}
```

If that doesn't work, I'd try

```
data: {filters: stringify(obj.filters)}
```

The exact syntax of the latter might be incorrect so please check that.

Comment: So I used the second version and now the parameter is coming through. The filters array has a single value and it comes as

[0] "[\"error\",\"warning\"]"

Comment: When you hit your action on the controller, have you examined the Request object to see if the values are hiding in there? This should allow to see the raw data being received by the server to ensure all the options are being sent back.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open up your browser, hit F12, and put a breakpoint directly on the $.ajax line (in the file in sources tab). Then, run that method. When the thread stops on the breakpoint, can you then open up the console tab, and type "obj.filters" and press enter.

Does it say "undefined"?

Looking at your code, it "shouldn't" be undefined, but that would certainly be a good start.

Also, stringifying (JSON.stringify())the information you send in, and then doing JObject calls (c#) to turn it back into an object array might work.

Comment: An easy way around this would be to take your object of string values, go through a for loop adding them to a single string with pipe delimiters, and pass the single string through AJAX. Then, parse it back to an array of strings in C# using "string[] myList = ajaxPostData.Split('|');"